# How to monitor browsers and capture urls without extensions

Tags: windows, macos, google-chrome, firefox, safari

How can I monitor browsers and capture URLs when they want to download files without using extensions and plugins? For example Internet Download Manager (the version I have) captures URLs from Chrome and Firefox without using extensions, or Free Download Manager does the same thing with Chrome (no extension is installed) but for Firefox it uses an extension and they also provide this service for almost all browsers out there.

1. Can this be done without extensions and plugins?
2. Can this be done for other operating systems like OSX and Linux ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. IDM Uses Layered Service Provider (LSP), which Windows provides it.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to simply intercept *all* traffic by browsers, and offer the option to download when uncommon filetypes (those that browsers would typically download rather than open) are navigated to.  There is probably a more elegant solution, but I might have it act as an odd sort of firewall--one that blocks certain types and instead downloads them on its own.

Comment: It is a good suggestion, but I doubt you can catch the url just before browser starts to download and also cancel it , and do it cleanly. I'll try this. Thank you.

Comment: well to intercept traffic you need to use proxy. I don't think they use proxies to intercept web traffics.